# Sort JSON by value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, sorting

how I can sort my json file by name -> value? I want to show by asc value of tag name. Any idea how to convert my json file?

Here is how look my JSON file:

```
[{
    "id": "105",
    "name": "FIAT",
    "active": true,
    "parentId": "1"
}, {
    "id": "106",
    "name": "AUDI",
    "active": true,
    "parentId": "1"
}, {
    "id": "107",
    "name": "BMW",
    "active": true,
    "parentId": "1"
}, {
    "id": "109",
    "name": "RENAULT",
    "active": true,
    "parentId": "1"
}]
```

I will be grateful if someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to sort on the client side or the server side?

Comment: Are you using PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: You should give more information; like said before, we need to know you want to do it in Php or js (eg. if you want to do it client side, you don't even have to change your JSON, and just sort your array on js with _.sort() )

Comment: Are you trying to sort the whole array of objects by the value of `name`, or are you trying to sort each individual object so that the keys show up in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I suggest to use [`Array#sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
var data = [
    { "id": "105", "name": "FIAT",    "active": true, "parentId": "1" },
    { "id": "106", "name": "AUDI",    "active": true, "parentId": "1" },
    { "id": "107", "name": "BMW",     "active": true, "parentId": "1" },
    { "id": "109", "name": "RENAULT", "active": true, "parentId": "1" }
];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Is localeCompare support extensive enough?

Comment: @Matthijs, what do you mean with *extensive*?

Comment: I was talking about browser support. Turns out Safari does not support locale comparisons in the way you describe; so if you're targeting that, another type of comparison is required.

Comment: yes, that's right. `a.name - b.name`

Answer (score 17):

Pretty straight-forward.

```js
var data = [
  { "id": "105", "name": "FIAT",    "active": true, "parentId": "1" },
  { "id": "106", "name": "AUDI",    "active": true, "parentId": "1" },
  { "id": "107", "name": "BMW",     "active": true, "parentId": "1" },
  { "id": "109", "name": "RENAULT", "active": true, "parentId": "1" }
];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.name > b.name;
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: you are actually calling 2 times data.sort(), the second call is redundant

Comment: Cant we use `return a.name - b.name` instead of `return a.name > b.name;`