# Sorting dictionary of objects by object value

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, lodash

If I have a JavaScript object like this:

```
list = {
    John: {
        DOB: '2017-02-01'
    },
    Rob: {
        DOB: '2016-07-09'
    },
}
```

How do I go about sorting this object into a list of objects sorted by their DOB.  I have lodash installed, so using that is an option.

I would like the result to be something mappable, ie an array such as:

```
sorted_keys = ['Rob','John']
```

or

```
sorted_array = [
    {
        Rob: {
            DOB: '2016-07-09'   
        }
    },
    {
        John: {
            DOB: '2017-02-01'   
        }
    },
]
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Did you see this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576041/sort-json-by-value

Comment: That is not the same thing:  that is an array of objects - this is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var list = {
    John: {
        DOB: '2017-02-01'
    },
    Rob: {
        DOB: '2016-07-09'
    }
}

var sortedKeys = Object.keys(list).sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(list[a].DOB) - new Date(list[b].DOB)
})

console.log(sortedKeys)
```

Or using arrow functions:

```js
let list = {
    John: {
        DOB: '2017-02-01'
    },
    Rob: {
        DOB: '2016-07-09'
    }
}

let sortedKeys = Object.keys(list).sort((a, b) => new Date(list[a].DOB) - new Date(list[b].DOB))

console.log(sortedKeys)
```

Answering on your comment if there were strings:

```js
let list = {
    John: {
        DOB: 'bbb'
    },
    Rob: {
        DOB: 'aaa'
    }
}

let sortedKeys = Object.keys(list).sort((a, b) => {
    if(list[a].DOB < list[b].DOB) return -1;
    if(list[a].DOB > list[b].DOB) return 1;
    return 0;
})

console.log(sortedKeys)
```

Comment: What if they were't dates - just strings?

Comment: @user1637466 added one more snippet

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that it's a bit strange that you have an object called `list` that's not a list, but an object.

It's possible to sort the key-value pairs in this object by following these steps:

- Extract the keys, using `Object.keys`
- Sort the keys by the alphabetic ordering of `list[key].DOB` values. Luckily, you can use `localeCompare` to compare dates in YYYY-MM-DD format.
- Map the sorted keys to object of the desired final structure

Like this:

```
let sorted = Object.keys(list)
  .sort((a, b) => list[a].DOB.localeCompare(list[b].DOB))
  .map(k => { return { [k]: list[k] } }));
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "Rob": {
      "DOB": "2016-07-09"
    }
  },
  {
    "John": {
      "DOB": "2017-02-01"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: The names and contents are just for demonstration purposes - this is not my actual object.

Comment: @user1637466 Apply the same logic to your real names and content, and the demonstrated technique will work just as well.