# How to sort by name through Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am just using `Jquery` to create a list of my products in my html document from the `json` data. I was just trying to be able to sort my products through clicking my heading name which will sort my products by alphabetical order.

I have researched on how to do this but cant find/understand how i can do this through using my data from `json`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
function drawPage() {
    $.get('/products', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var prod = data.products;

        for(var i=0; i<prod.length; i++){
        var el = document.createElement('P');
        el.innerHTML = prod[i].name;

            $('#app').append(el);
        }
    })
}
document.addEventListener('load', drawPage());
```

Comment: why java/python?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the comparing function to sort your objects array by product name.

**Prototype:**

```
function drawPage() {
    $.get('/products', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var prods = data.products;

        //sorting by product names
        prods.sort(function(a, b){
          var x = a.name.toLowerCase();
          var y = b.name.toLowerCase();
          if (x < y) {return -1;}
          if (x > y) {return 1;}
          return 0;
        });

        for(var i=0; i<prods.length; i++){
           var el = document.createElement('P');
           el.innerHTML = prods[i].name;
           $('#app').append(el);
        }
    })
}
document.addEventListener('load', drawPage());
```

You can also sort the json directly before importing it in your array via:
[Sort JSON by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576041/sort-json-by-value)

Comment: If im using a button in my html which can toggle between sorted and unsorted.
    <button onclick="sorting()">All Products</button>
would i just create a new function 
    function sorting() {
and include the sorting code? Or would i have to somehow include it all and link it back to html all within my one function?

Comment: @James: 

Then you need to save the state of the button (a bool would be enough) and do the sorting or not depending on the value of that boolean. Each time the user click on the button you change its value

Answer (score 0):

```js
var prod = [
{name: "truck", price: "20000"},
{name: "car", price: "50000"},
{name: "bus", price: "30000"}]

function SortByName(x,y) {
      return ((x.name == y.name) ? 0 : ((x.name > y.name) ? 1 : -1 ));
}
$(function () {
        prod.sort(SortByName);
        console.log(prod)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```